# Different respond time from the server for the same application

Tags: server, windows-server-2008

Hi everyone I have one web application application that is hosted on a windows server and with windows sql management system, I run the application twice and tested it on 2 different set of data with the same size, i get very different server respond time.
note one of the applications i was using in incognito mode but i don not think this is the issue. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEbOQ.png)

I tried to clean the server and restart it but still same issue.